# How can a background image be 100% height and width

Tags: css

I have used `background image` in `body` but can it be responsive so that the height & width is set to 100%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this CSS Tricks Post](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/):

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rich Peck, It is so helpful.

Comment: No problem! What kind of site are you building?